# Edit objects in json array based on strings in another array with jq

Tags: json, jq

For some reason I just can't wrap my head around jq. I've been going around in circles for hours trying to accomplish what I think is not too difficult a task.
With json consisting of two arrays as input, I want to search for objects in the second array whereby the `name` field value is an element of the first array, and then add a field, say `"found": true`, to those objects.

```
[
    [
        "test1",
        "test2",
        "test3"
    ],
    [
        {
            "name": "test5",
            "data": "five"
        },
        {
            "name": "test1",
            "data": "four"
        },
        {
            "name": "test2",
            "data": "three"
        },
        {
            "name": "test3",
            "data": "six"
        }
    ]
]
```

My best guess so far starts with...
`.[0] as $tn | (.[1] | .[] | .name | in($tn[]))`
but that is not getting me close to where i want to go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your attempt has only two issues: First, you need [`select`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#select%28boolean_expression%29) to filter out certain items. Second, there are two (confusingly named) functions: The one called [`in`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#in) tests for the existence of keys in objects, the other one called [`IN`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#SQL-StyleOperators) searches for occurrence in a stream or array. You need the latter.

```bash
.[0] as $tn | .[1][] | select(.name | IN($tn[])) | .found = true
```

```json
{
  "name": "test1",
  "data": "four",
  "found": true
}
{
  "name": "test2",
  "data": "three",
  "found": true
}
{
  "name": "test3",
  "data": "six",
  "found": true
}
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/RyZrXcof-Ke)

If, however, you wanted to retain the original structure, you need to retain the top-level context until the end of your filter, while manipulating parts of it using updates `|=` as in:

```bash
.[0] as $tn | (.[1][] | select(.name | IN($tn[]))).found = true
```

```json
[
  [
    "test1",
    "test2",
    "test3"
  ],
  [
    {
      "name": "test5",
      "data": "five"
    },
    {
      "name": "test1",
      "data": "four",
      "found": true
    },
    {
      "name": "test2",
      "data": "three",
      "found": true
    },
    {
      "name": "test3",
      "data": "six",
      "found": true
    }
  ]
]
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/0BlQiBKSjk5)

And to set the boolean flag on all items, just assign, don't select:

```bash
.[0] as $tn | .[1][] |= (.found = (.name | IN($tn[])))
```

```json
[
  [
    "test1",
    "test2",
    "test3"
  ],
  [
    {
      "name": "test5",
      "data": "five",
      "found": false
    },
    {
      "name": "test1",
      "data": "four",
      "found": true
    },
    {
      "name": "test2",
      "data": "three",
      "found": true
    },
    {
      "name": "test3",
      "data": "six",
      "found": true
    }
  ]
]
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/NeqCUFX7hli)

Comment: Thank you very much. Just what I needed. I hadn't realized IN and in were distinct functions!

Answer (score 2):

Close enough. Use `IN` to check for items in a stream and then assign the new property:

```
first as $names
| .[1][] | select(.name|IN($names[]))
| .found = true
```

Output:

```json
{
  "name": "test1",
  "data": "four",
  "found": true
}
{
  "name": "test2",
  "data": "three",
  "found": true
}
{
  "name": "test3",
  "data": "six",
  "found": true
}
```

If you want to keep the input structure and only add `found` to the matching elements in the nested array, use parentheses:

```
first as $names
| (.[1][] | select(.name|IN($names[]))).found = true
```

Output:

```json
[
  [
    "test1",
    "test2",
    "test3"
  ],
  [
    {
      "name": "test5",
      "data": "five"
    },
    {
      "name": "test1",
      "data": "four",
      "found": true
    },
    {
      "name": "test2",
      "data": "three",
      "found": true
    },
    {
      "name": "test3",
      "data": "six",
      "found": true
    }
  ]
]
```

And finally to transform and extract only the second array (as array):

```
first as $names
| (.[1] | map(select(.name|IN($names[])).found = true))
```

Output:

```json
[
  {
    "name": "test5",
    "data": "five"
  },
  {
    "name": "test1",
    "data": "four",
    "found": true
  },
  {
    "name": "test2",
    "data": "three",
    "found": true
  },
  {
    "name": "test3",
    "data": "six",
    "found": true
  }
]
```

To keep only the matching elements (note the `|` before assignment of `.found`):

```
first as $names
| (.[1] | map(select(.name|IN($names[])) | .found = true))
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This solution worked as well as the one from @pmf but I can only mark one as accepted.